# Why was my question marked as offtopic?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [DOS (MS-DOS, FreeDOS, DR DOS) equivalent to UNIX "time" command?](https://superuser.com/questions/1736746/dos-ms-dos-freedos-dr-dos-equivalent-to-unix-time-command)

I wonder why my question was marked as offtopic.
I followed these rules:
https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

There it says:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

```
computer hardware,
computer software, or
personal and home computer networking
```

**That is true. It is about computer software.** In this case DOS and a programm that can measure the time a program takes.

> and it is not about …

```
programming and software development,
video games or consoles,
websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,
```

**Exactly.** It's not about programming, not about video games or consoles, not about websites, electronic devices and all the other stuff mentioned above.

> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

**Exactly, all rules fullfilled.** my question was 100 % on-topic according to the above rules but it was still marked as off-topic. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: so the question was closed under the "software recommendations" rule.  in theory the question would be safe if you asked "how do I do X", rather than "what tool am i looking for to do X". yes, I know the distinction seems somewhat pedantic, but .... anyway, try touching up your question if you like, and see if you can get an admin to reconsider.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Frustrating. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2):

The question shouldn't have been closed as off-topic, since it is asking about MS-DOS/FreeDOS commands. The OP didn't know  ahead of time that there doesn't exist such a command  built-in in MS-DOS/FreeDOS. I voted to reopen.

Comment: I have a paltry 156 over here, but I'd agree, it's clearly on topic.